# getting parametters on a POST method with java ee

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a form with a POST method.

**First**, my SERVLET (in a doGet) retrieves the parameter "myParametter". I have a :

```
myParametter = yq1+81L7kqNcqObO9GDrYQTvgNONcvAcqSM53Po/J2Q=
```

Then I pass it to my JSP (which contains the form).

I wanted to have the same parameter and pass it to doPost (from the same SERVLET), and I have:

```
myParametter = yq1%2081L7kqNcqObO9GDrYQTvgNONcvAcqSM53Po/J2Q =
```

Basically the **"+"** is replaced by **"% 20"**.

I can't use URLDecode because it deprecated.

Comment: The parameter is generated by a hashing function using SHA256. Hope it will help to give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you will need to change your **SHA256** to **SHA1**

Please read more in this valuable link [SHA1 vs SHA256](https://www.keycdn.com/support/sha1-vs-sha256/) .

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @YagamiLight, i'll tedt that and come back later.